# Should the personal medical advice rule be changed?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Simply put, I believe that while good intentioned, the “no personal medical advice” rule is doing more harm than good.

You have to remember that people come here from Google. If SE isn’t answering these questions, they’ll keep going on through Google until they find something that seems to fit - and in so doing, they’ll get the advice that you refused to provide. The link given has an example of someone asking about fatigue and then suffering serious consequences because they drank a lot of water and exercised - now consider for a moment that that patient is likely coming here from Googling “fatigue low energy” or something, and if they don’t get an answer, they’ll go to the next site on the list - which might give the exact same harmful generic advice that you’re concerned about, or it might give pseudoscience “alternative medicine” advice that actively harms them in other ways.

By contrast, if Answers for these questions are given here, then we can be sure that they are high quality answers given by medical professionals - even if they might not be as good as an in-person examination, then they’re still better than going onto the next site that may just be a medical listicle and not consider their personal circumstances at all. Additionally, while the patient may not give a full accounting of their medical history, that’s what the comments are for - to ask questions for additional information that can help produce a higher quality answer. If someone posts “I have a lot of fatigue” without enough detail, then you should use the comments to ask them “Do you have conditions X, Y, or Z”?

As a result of these factors, I believe that the current policy is counterproductive to patient health and should be changed. Instead of the current policy, I would suggest adding a note in the sidebar that says something like “This site is not a replacement for seeing your doctor”, and maybe putting a banner on personal medical advice questions that advises people who find them through Google to consider if it matches their circumstances- and to ask a question of their own if it doesn’t.

Comment: `"By contrast, if Answers for these questions are given here, then we can be sure that they are high quality answers given by medical professionals"` -- How so? There are several high-rep users here I believe to be licensed physicians, but I have absolutely no way of verifying that. They could be brilliant 14 year olds for all I know.  Stackexchange doesn't guarantee credentials. It only provides upvotes and downvotes.

Comment: @CareyGregory Because the entire point of Stack Exchange is for experts in a field to provide answers - and while you can't verify their medical certification, you can verify their Reputation score and the Answers they've given in the past. If you're not even going to trust that experts are experts, what's the point of having this SE site in the first place?

Comment: @nick012000 - You can't guarantee that anyone on any site is actually an expert, or just someone really good with google. That's why the voting system exists. You could say the same statement about any SE site, "how do I know you know what you're talking about?"

Comment: @JohnP You know that they know what they're talking about because of their Reputation score. That's the entire point of it: the verification of expertise on that topic.

Comment: @nick012000 Reputation is mostly just correlated with the number of questions you answer. It helps filter some of the junk answers but does not identify experts; it definitely does not identify MDs. At least several of the top-20 rep users here are *definitely not* MDs, myself included.

Comment: What @BryanKrause said. I am a top rep user, and my highest level of medical schooling was paramedic out of an ER for the USAF.

Comment: While not perfect perhaps there’s a way individuals could post their StackExchange user ID in their Doximity profile.

Answer (score 7):

> By contrast, if Answers for these questions are given here, then we
>   can be sure that they are high quality answers given by medical
>   professionals

Oh? How would we be sure? There are several high-rep users here I believe to be licensed physicians, but I have absolutely no way of verifying that. They could be brilliant 14-year olds for all I know. Even if they provided us with their name, links to their licensing credentials, etc, they could still be a brilliant 14-year old impersonating a real doctor.

Stackexchange doesn't guarantee credentials. It only provides upvotes and downvotes.

I am not in favor of allowing brilliant 14-year olds to provide medical advice for the reasons that DoctorWhom elucidated in [this canonical answer](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/how-long-can-this-site-be-popular-if-everybody-is-asked-to-see-a-doctor/748#748).

Comment: You did not address the main point of my post: if these questions are not answered on SE where there is quality control, they will be answered by the next site the person finds on Google instead.

Comment: @nick012000 That's true, but we have no control over other sites and where people find their information. All we can control is what they find here.

Comment: Yes, and that's exactly my point. Choosing inaction is also choosing an action. Would you rather get their information somewhere where you can control its quality, or somewhere you can't? Which one leads to better patient outcomes?

Comment: @nick012000 I don't know, but I would prefer to be a source of no information rather than bad information.

Comment: My point is that by being a source of no information, you *become* a source of bad information, de facto, because they'll go onto the next site on Google instead.

Comment: No, sorry, I'm not accepting blame for what people find and believe on the internet.

Comment: When you're running a site like this, you should. It's an ethical obligation that comes along with your moderator diamond. That's why SE's answer rules involve making sure that they're useful for other people - because people will find them years from now with Google searches.

Comment: Oh come on, there is no ethical obligation what so ever for volunteers to do anything.  People are so happy to oblige others to do things free for them.  The sense of entitlement is overwhelming.

Comment: @nick012000 If you think I have an ethical obligation to allow all questions you deem fit because I agreed to volunteer as a moderator then I think you should contact the CM team and volunteer to help me.

Comment: @CareyGregory If it'll get this policy overturned, sure, I'll nominate myself for the next set of elections.

Comment: @GrahamChiu That is completely untrue. When you volunteer for a position, you assume the ethical responsibilities of that position - for instance, if you're volunteering as a Sunday School teacher at a church, you're bound by a number of ethical responsibilities regarding the wellbeing of the children in your care.

Comment: It seems you don't understand that moderators don't set rules. The community sets rules. You won't be able to change those rules once you become a moderator. You can only enforce the rules the community has agreed upon.

Comment: of the top 4 ranked users here only one is a physician, and is no longer active on this site. the top ranked user studies nutrients.  You @nick012000 have no idea what is happening on this site.

Comment: @CareyGregory Hence this question to try to change them - and you're omitting a possible means for the rules to change: SE corporate ordering you to do so (and they might, if those rules are going against their policies or goals, which I suspect might be happening here).

Comment: @nick012000 LOL, okay, we're done here. You go ahead and get SE corporate to change things.

Comment: This site was set up specifically excluding personal medical advice as one of its prime directives. If this were to happen we'd be overwhelmed with bad advice again about magic water and whatever, and we'd be snowed under deleting answers etc. You have zero idea of what this site has been through and display an ugly arrogance to boot.

Comment: @nick012000 There is nothing wrong with making a meta post to try to change the rules (though for this particular one, it's been suggested so many times that I'd hope you would have at least looked at those previous requests first...). However, it's also totally reasonable for the community to disagree with you.